# Apple watchOS 1 - Is it possible to store local data on Watch App itself

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, watchkit, watchos

I want to personalize watch app per installation on Watch. So I need to store some local data on the watch which will be reset after I uninstalled watch app on the watch (or after unpair - pair).

I tried to use `NSUserDefaults` but records remain as it is even if I unpair and pair the watch again. It seems `NSUserDefaults` are kept on iOS side and not cleared even after unpair.

Note: My watch application is designed on watchOS 1

Comment: That is correct, `NSUserDefaults` are not wiped from iOS or watchOS until the app is uninstalled. Have you tried manually deleting the data after unpairing?